# The opposite of a paean

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm wondering what the opposite of a paean might be, or if there's such a word in English. I thought there was, but I can't think of it.

The example I'm using is that Ernest Cline's *Ready Player One*. It's a novel about a dystopian future where people spend all their time jacked into a virtual reality called the OASIS, neglecting nature and choosing not to live in the real world. Cline's work is a warning against the direction in which we may be headed. This seems to be, to wit, the opposite of a paean to technology. What would this be called?

Comment: How about _naeap_? _A naeap of condemnation_ sounds just as pretentious as _a paean of praise_. And nobody would know how to pronounce it, either.

Comment: If we are going to make stuff up, why not naean, but pronounced nā' on, just to further confuse matters?

Comment: ......a panning

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that a "paean" is a "song of triumph, praise" (see [παιάν](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3D%2apaia%2Fn), *sub* II, and I'm aware that English isn't Greek!), my inclination would be to go with "lament" or "dirge" (a song of death or defeat).

If you wanted to reflect the opposite of "paean", there is a corresponding term in Greek, [θρῆνος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dqrh%3Dnos), which comes into English as a "threne". The most recent example in the OED is from 1960, R. Eberhart, *Coll. Poems 1930–60*, p. 14: "The perfect lament, and **threne** of sorrow's throat". As an adjective, you've got "threnetic" which might apply nicely to the dystopia you're writing about.

Fairly obscure, it has to be said, but that's not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: In song form, it's known as a _threnody_, as in Penderecki's _Threnody for the Victims of Hiroshima_.

Answer (score 3):

A *jeremiad*, from the Book of Jeremiah, is a lament and warning about the evils that are to come (because, as anyone over 35 knows, the world is going to the dogs).

A *Philippic* (from Cicero's speeches against one Philip) is a tirade of invective.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a proper English antonym, but German offers up a *Trauerlied*, or "a song of mourning." That's probably as close as you're going to get to an antonym for *paean*. The closest English word would be *elegy*, but that is more melancholic than angst-ridden.

If you are talking about an attack on something, rather than mourning what's lost, then *screed* probably fits the bill best.